# In Highcharts, how do we propertly place multi-pyramid charts?

Tags: highcharts

For example, there are 4 pyramid, I want to place them like 2 * 2. So their centers should be `['25%','25%'], ['75%','25%'], ['25%','75%'],['75%','75%']`,
[image]

you can see the second row of pyramids fly to the top of first row.

then I came out with an idea that "why not try second row centers with `['25%','-25%', '75%','-25%']`?"
[image]
Yeah! It works! Wait! Where are my datalabels?

So, I'm wondering how do we place them propertly without losing datalabels?

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/scottszb1987/wyqxLkxh/

Comment: I think that this problem is already reported on Highcharts github. Here you can find link to this topic: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5500 And here you can see an example with workaround from this topic: https://jsfiddle.net/wyqxLkxh/1/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński, thanks for pointing out, that issue was actually reported by me :) Thanks all the same.